# Cuda dynamic parallelism: depth of children threads one can create

Tags: cuda

I am reading the CUDA programming guide which I find dense. I came to the section where they explain that a parent grid can create a child grid, and the parent grid is considered completed only when all its spawned child threads have completed.

My question is: how "deep" is the parent-child tree allowed to grow in Cuda: are these only constrained by the compute capabilities of the hardware in question, e.g one can for example spawn as many parent/children blocks of threads as he/she wants, provided we don't exceed the max number of threads that can run on the hardware at once, or are there further constraints? I am asking this because absent this capability I don't see how recursion can be implemented on GPUs.

thanks,
Amine

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#nesting-and-synchronization-depth

Comment: @RobertCrovella if the max depth of nesting is 24 as per documentation, and we consider the example of calling a kernel that operates on both halves of an array in a recursive way, in the process splitting the size by 2 at each spawned child kernel, then the max size of the array to be considered is 2^24 ?

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct.  However doesn't it also mean that you (at the last level of nesting) are launching 2^24 kernels (or maybe its' 2^23).  If that's what you have in mind: 1. There are other limits you may run into, such as the launch pending limit.  2 It's probably going to be a bad idea, performance wise.  The kernel launch process has overhead, and the GPU is not well utilized when you are launching kernels that have a low thread or block count.  The general advice would be to find another way to realize the algorithm.  In my experience, kernel-level recursion is not widely used.

Comment: @RobertCrovella it was just a theoretical consideration I had in mind since it is something we take for granted on CPU single-threaded apps. You are right that at the last level, we have 2^23 kernels, i.e threads, but I assume this is way beyond the constraints of even the latest GPU?

Comment: I think you may be confused about how a GPU executes threads.  For example, in your question you state: "provided we don't exceed the max number of threads that can run on the hardware at once".  I'm not sure why that would be a factor here.  Regardless, 2^23 threads is not way beyond the constraints of GPUs (even the oldest GPUs) but attempting to launch 2^23 kernels at once is probably not workable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: how "deep" is the parent-child tree allowed to grow in Cuda

The [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#nesting-and-synchronization-depth) indicates a maximum nesting depth of 24.

As indicated in the documentation, there typically will be other limits that you may hit first, before actually reaching a nesting depth of 24.  One of these would be general limits on device kernel launches, including memory requirements as well as launch pending limits.  Another possible limit is the synchronization limit.  This has to do with whether a parent kernel is explicitly waiting on a child kernel to complete (e.g. via device-side `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`, and to what depth this synchronization is extended.

> provided we don't exceed the max number of threads that can run on the hardware at once

None of this depends explicitly on how many threads are in the parent kernel, or child kernel(s).  CUDA kernels don't have any basic limitation on the number of threads the hardware can run at once, and neither does CUDA Dynamic Parallelism (CDP).

As a practical matter then, large depth CDP launches may run into a variety of limits.  Further, such design patterns may not be the best from a performance perspective.  A CDP launch has time and resource overheads associated with it, and for any pattern that would subdivide the work this way, it's generally desirable in a CUDA kernel to do *more* work in the kernel, not less.